Write DIRT vegetation Index in Raster Calculator for weed detection - QGIS
Research with DIRT vegetation index explanation for weed detection HERE

For weed detection we choose a red threshold value β that is above the
maximal red reflectance of the weed species. If the measured intensity
R of an arbitrary image pixel is higher then the threshold β, the sign
of the NDVI value is inverted (switched to the opposite sign),
indicating that this pixel is not a weed pixel.
With the signum function sign( β-R) it is possible to combine the new
decision criteria and the NDVI in one formula, called the Difference
Index with Red Threshold (DIRT):
**

DIRT = sign( β-R) * (NIR-R) / (NIR+R)

**
During our test the value β was fixed to 0.12 and never changed. But
under special circumstances, depending on the materials of the mulched
areas, this threshold may be adjusted in the range of 0.08 to 0.15.

How to write correctly the formula above in raster calculator inside QGIS?
My multispectral raster layers are:

result_RedEdge
result_Red
result_Green
result_NIR

I tried:
     if ( 
0.12-"result_Red@1" >= 0,
 ( "result_NIR@1" - "result_Red@1" )  /  ("result_NIR@1" + "result_Red@1"  ),
(-1)*( "result_NIR@1" - "result_Red@1" )  /  ("result_NIR@1" + "result_Red@1") 
       )

But yield wrong numbers like below:


For some reason the IF statement didn't work as expected. So, searching in QGIS manual I found a way to do the conditional using a mask.
For more information see this link
The formula is:
((0.12-"result_Red@1") >= 0) * (( "result_NIR@1" - "result_Red@1" )  /  ("result_NIR@1" + "result_Red@1"  )) + ((0.12-"result_Red@1") < 0) * (-1)*(( "result_NIR@1" - "result_Red@1" )  /  ("result_NIR@1" + "result_Red@1"  ))
